# Is it faster to iterate an std::vector<int> by references to elements or by index?

Tags: c++, performance, reference, iterator

Let `v` be a `std::vector<int>`. Which of the two methods below is faster for iterating over its elements?

`for (auto& el: v) {...el...}`
or
`for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {...v[i]...}`

I'm seeing the former in a lot of competitive programming solutions, however I don't get how it can be faster than the one below unless the vector objects are something different from a built-in type

Comment: Unrelated, "competitive coding solutions" is an oxymoron.

Comment: Akso, depending on the implementation. The range-for is easier to read and has one less identifier.